Short story regarding a scientist who helps the Russians design weapons that keep failing in use due to Russian incompetence?
One of the weapons was a jetpack that the Russians used to try to invade the West but get disrupted by U.S. bombers.

Hi, welcome to SF&F.  When and where did you read this?  Were the devices actually science fictional, or was this more of a thriller/spycraft story?
